# how to change axes values for a plot in r

Tags: r, plot

i have this plot :

```
library(gplots) 
y <- c(2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)
B <- c(249.3543, 249.5647, 392.4330, 383.8343 ,289.9862, 541.6652 ,415.5451)
StdB <- c(64.61869, 59.60757, 46.54578 ,55.59268 ,51.16547 ,59.10967 ,58.53109)
plotCI(y, B,  StdB, StdB,
         sfrac = 0.01, gap=0.2, type="p",lwd=2.5,xlab='Years',ylab ='Values')
```

in my plot in axes i have some static values but i want it to only show the values that i have them in my B.
i already checked the arguments  of plotci i didn't find something for personalizing it.
is there a way for it?

Comment: What package contains `plotCI`? You should include the `library(XXXX)` statement so that we all know what you are using.

Comment: i didn't use any library .its a function in r

Comment: ?? Not in my copy of R

Comment: `plotCI` is in the gplots package.  Just edited the question to show this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add plot related arguments to `plotCI`.  Have a look at ?`par`
Here I've set yaxt to 'n' to disable printing of tick marks and values on the y-axis.  I've changed the y-axis limits with ylim.

The function `Axis` specifies where the tick marks and values should go. Side = 2 specifies the y-axis.

```
library(gplots)  
y <- c(2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)
B <- c(249.3543, 249.5647, 392.4330, 383.8343 ,289.9862, 541.6652 ,415.5451)
StdB <- c(64.61869, 59.60757, 46.54578 ,55.59268 ,51.16547 ,59.10967 ,58.53109)
plotCI(y, B,  StdB, StdB,
       sfrac = 0.01, gap=0.2, type="p",lwd=2.5,xlab='Years',ylab ='Values', yaxt = 'n', ylim = c(0, 600))
Axis(at = c(50, 500), side = 2 )
```